# On iOS, is it possible to setup an NEPacketTunnelProvider VPN only for the containing app?

Tags: ios, vpn, tunnel, networkextension, nevpnmanager

I'm currently writing a library that will be used by different apps.  One of the features I would like to provide to clients of my library is the ability to setup a VPN using a custom tunneling protocol that will be utilized only by the client app.  i.e. All other apps on the device should not be routed through the VPN.  I am aware that *Per-App VPN*, allows one or more apps to be routed through the VPN.  However, I do not like to deal with  MDM restrictions.  In my case, I only need the tunnel for the containing app but without the MDM requirement.  Would this be possible?  If not, are there alternatives outside of using Network Extensions?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible.
As you said you need the Per-App VPN, and so you need MDM.

Otherwise you will get the packets from all the apps.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way you can achieve the same result as what you want.
If you know the destination ip addresses of the containing app you can just set the 
ipv4Settings.includedRoutes = []
to be only containing the remote host ip address. By this way you can make it almost nearly only for the containing app.